# How to iterate over a list of URL?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the links of this page : [link](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&)

I made it, but my end goal is to scrape over multiple pages several links in order to scrape informations on all those hotels.

Here's the beginning of my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('links.csv', 'w') as file :
    file.write('links')

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)


cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)

for k in range(1):

    my_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url"]')

    links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in my_elems]

    links = [link.replace('\n','') for link in links]

    with open('links.csv', 'a') as file :
        for i in range(len(links)):
            file.write(links[i] + "\n")


        next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_results_table"]/div[4]/nav/ul/li[3]/a')
      
        next.click()

    file.close()

df = pd.read_csv('links.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

And after I would like to iterate over all the link I stored (here I scrape only one pages : `range(1)` but it's only for training)

I guess it would be more handy to store the link in a list but I couldn't find how to do that. So far now I stored them in a dataframe but it's not quite as handy.

The goal would be to iterate all the link, like that :

```
pointforts = []
hotels = []
notes = []

for url in df: 

    results = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    ...
```

But I cannot find how to do that with the dataframe.

So I have 2 requests :

- How to do that with a dataframe ?
- How to have a list of links instad of a dataframe ? (I would rather have this solution)

And last thing, Do I need more `time.sleep()` ?

Comment: Yes, please use `time.sleep()` when recursively making requests, you don't want to ddos the webpage.

Comment: First think use proxies, next use `time.sleep()`

Comment: ddos ? proxies ?